# Magento 2 Override Model using Plugin

Tags: module, model, plugin, magento-2.2.5

I have to override magento 2 code model file in the custom module.

I have to override below method from Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address to my custom module and I have to change value of $amount.

```
public function validateMinimumAmount()
{
    $storeId = $this->getQuote()->getStoreId();
    $validateEnabled = $this->_scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
        'sales/minimum_order/active',
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        $storeId
    );
    if (!$validateEnabled) {
        return true;
    }

    if (!$this->getQuote()->getIsVirtual() xor $this->getAddressType() == self::TYPE_SHIPPING) {
        return true;
    }

    $amount = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
        'sales/minimum_order/amount',
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        $storeId
    );
    $taxInclude = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
        'sales/minimum_order/tax_including',
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        $storeId
    );
    $taxes = $taxInclude ? $this->getBaseTaxAmount() : 0;

    return ($this->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount() + $taxes >= $amount);
}
```

app/code/vendor/module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address">
        <plugin name="my_address_plugin" type="vendor\module\Plugin\AddressPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>    
</config>
```

can anyone please help? I'm not sure which method to use before, after or around and how to set custom value for $amount using my plugin.

Comment: I would suggest around or after method.

Comment: can you please post answer?

Comment: Plugins will not work here, plugins are for modifying the parameters or results or both.

Comment: @Anshu then what you suggest?

Comment: May I know the requirement.

Comment: currently magento only provides same minimum amount for all customer groups. I have to pass amount there customer group wise.

Comment: You can also use preference for it.

Comment: By preference I have to totally override Model file. It's not good.

Comment: Preference can be used but I would suggest checking if you can use Constructor Arguments overriding technique as explained at https://inchoo.net/magento-2/overriding-classes-magento-2/

Comment: @Anshu not getting your point about Constructor Arguments overriding

Comment: Go through the shared link, the link has a good explanation of different overriding techniques in Magento2.

Comment: You can use an around plugin to completely replace the method. However, you can also use argument replacement to replace $this->_scopeConfig in the constructor. When this path is called, ''sales/minimum_order/amount', you can return your special value. For any other path, return the parent value.

Comment: @Magecode answer added with working code snippet. Obviously, update the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is how to accomplish this with argument replacement. Essentially, we are replacing the current instance of `Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface` but ONLY for the one specific class. This is the preferred method because we don't want to do a full class override like some commenters suggest, that would just be greedy. In this case, we accomplish our goal with minimal interference to the rest of the code.

In your di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="scopeConfig" xsi:type="object">Vendorname\Modulename\Model\ScopeConfig</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Create a model at Model/ScopeConfig.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Model;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

class ScopeConfig extends \Magento\Framework\App\Config
{
    /**
     * @param null|string $path
     * @param string      $scope
     * @param null|string $scopeCode
     *
     * @return mixed|string
     */
    public function getValue(
        $path = null,
        $scope = ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT,
        $scopeCode = null
    ) {
        $result = parent::getValue($path, $scope, $scopeCode);

        if ($path === 'sales/minimum_order/amount') {
            $result = 'do your logic and return some special value here';
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: This Model code is executing but some issue

I have changed $result = 60. In cart product with $59 and tax is $5.90 so total is $64.90. And in admin Include Tax to Amount is set to Yes, but although "Proceed to checkout" is disabled.

Comment: I can't write the entire module for you. However, I did show you the best way to modify the $amount variable as requested in your question. If you have the ability to modify that value as requested please accept the answer. Thank you!

Comment: I need one help. when I'm going to call helper in this code. it's not working.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function resolve() on null in magento225\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config.php:69

Comment: protected $_helper;
    
    public function __construct(\Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $helper)
    {
        $this->_helper = $helper;
    }

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use after method to change the $amount response. Please follow:

*app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address">
        <plugin name="my_address_plugin" type="vendor\Module\Plugin\AddressPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>    
</config>
```

*app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/AddressPlugin*

```
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address as QuoteAddress;

class AddressPlugin
{

    /**
     * @param QuoteAddress $subject
     * @param boolean $result
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function afterValidateMinimumAmount(QuoteAddress $subject, $result)
    {
        if ($handle) {
            return ($handle >= $result);
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

The `$result` is the current method response. So you can manipulate as you want, for example, using a `$handle` to do something you need.

Comment: Can you please write code snippet in brief. I have tried but it is not working. It's taking minimum amount from default magento not from plugin file

Comment: I have to change minimum amount and pass my custom minimum amount value there.

Comment: It's just an example. Your should implement your logic there. Try to replace `return $result` to `return 1.00`.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you want to override the validateMinimumAmount method in the Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address class. You can achieve this using a plugin.

Create a plugin class in your module:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/AddressPlugin.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class AddressPlugin
{
 /**
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address $subject
 * @param \Closure $proceed
 * @return bool
 */
public function aroundValidateMinimumAmount(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address $subject,
    \Closure $proceed
) {
    // Your custom logic to set a new value for $amount
    $newAmount = 100; // Set your custom value

    // Override the $amount value
    $this->setCustomAmount($newAmount);

    // Call the original method
    return $proceed();
}

/**
 * Set a custom value for $amount
 *
 * @param float $amount
 */
 private function setCustomAmount($amount)
 {
     // Implement your logic to set the custom value for $amount
  }
}
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
          <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address">
          <plugin name="my_address_plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\AddressPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
          </type>
     </config>
```

This plugin uses the around method to modify the behavior of the validateMinimumAmount method. The around method allows you to execute custom code before and after the original method, and you can modify the input parameters and return value as needed.